# How to rollback data in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had unfortunately deleted data from database by using following query in SQL Server

```
exec usp_delete_cascade "someTable", "id='somexyz'"
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get back my data?

Is this possible?

Comment: I think it is impossible, at least you have backup of your database and can restore data from there

Comment: You can rollback a transaction and you can restore a backup, one or the other. Given the question you most likely only have the latter option. If you don't have a backup, but you do have a transaction log, you may be able to reproduce the database up to the point of just before executing that statement. You would then restore to an earlier point (or recreate an empty database) and replay the transaction log. I have no experience with this kind of thing. Backup is your friend.

Comment: Restore the most recent backup, maybe .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of transactions - implicit and explicit.

**Implicit transaction** is used every time you do DML statement (in your case delete). This transaction is not user handled. And it is not true your qry did not run under transaction.

**Explicit transaction** can be defined by user (with begin transaction). When you do not specify transaction, there are only implicit transactions, which are autocommited when statement success.

There is a few ways how to data recover, but never with 100% success and without work. You have to use some **external program** as SysTools SQL Recovery, ApexSQL Recover or Veeam. Level of recovery depends on your storage use and your server configuration.

Only one 100% way is prevension (and backups, change tracking etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to recover with this tool of ApexSQL, but you would think in backup and measures to avoid this kind of problem.

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_recover.aspx

Obviously is a third party tool and you would pay for using it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your server config. But, by default, SQL Server does not starts transaction when executing query. So, if you do not started transaction, or transaction started, but commited, rollback is impossible.

Other ways to restore the data: if your database recovery model is set to full, and you have diff or full backup, youre lucky. If no, data is missing forewer.